# SetInterval with scope in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
var i=0;
var t={
  a:function(){
    this.timer=setInterval(this.b,30);
  },
  b:function(){
    if(i++<1){
      console.log(this);
    }
  }
};
t.a();
```

Why did I get the [circular object global]? I want 'this' is refers to the object `t`;

How can I get that?

And I know how to resolve this problem, the below codes is right result:

```
var i=0;
var t={
  a:function(){
    var that=this;
    this.timer=setInterval(function(){
      that.b();
    },30);
  },
  b:function(){
    if(i++<1){
      console.log(this);
    }
  }
};
t.a();
```

Comment: So if you know how to fix the problem... why do you ask?

Comment: @migg i want to know why :)

Comment: Please do not confuse *context* (the `thisArg`) with [variable] *scope*

Answer (score 2):

You need to either use [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) or [`Function.prototype.call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) to re-assign context, as a function called in this way loses it's context to the global scope. This is most easily observed in the following example

```
o = { // an object
    foo: 1,
    bar: function () { // function assuming `this` is `o`
        return this.foo;
    }
};
f = o.bar; // function `f` loses scope of `o`
o.bar();   // 1,         o.foo is defined
f();       // undefined, window.foo is undefined
```

Here are some examples of the solution in your case

```
// bind
function scopedInterval(func, delay, context) {
    return window.setInterval(func.bind(context), delay);
}
// or call
function scopedInterval(func, delay, context) {
    return window.setInterval(function () {func.call(context);}, delay);
}
```

In these examples, you'd pass `this` as the 3rd parameter, i.e.

```
this.timer = scopedInterval(this.b, 30, this);
```

---

If you don't do this, the context of `setInterval` is `window` (I always invoke it as `window.setInterval` so I don't forget this)

Comment: this doesn't explain why. And the reason it's because it's a bug of the language

Comment: @Geeo The only reason I can't +1 your answer is (as you repeated in your comment) you say "it's a bug of the language". That's an opinion and whilst I agree _JavaScript_ has a silly definition of how `this` should work in these cases and it might "bug people", I don't consider it "a bug".

Comment: Btw, it's much simpler than `call` in this case: just `context.func()`

Comment: @PaulS. yeah, it's not *really* a bug, still a bad design.

Answer (score 0):

As Crockford says in his amazing book: "Javascripts: The Good Parts":

> When a function is not the property of an object, then it is invoked as a function [this is the case of setInterval]. When a function is invoked with this pattern, 'this' is bound to the global object. This was a mistake in the design of the language. Had the language been designed correctly, when the inner function is invoked, 'this' would still be bound to the 'this' variable of the outer function. A consequence of this error is that a method cannot employ an inner function to help it do its work because the inner function does not share the method's access to the object as its 'this' is bound to the wrong value. [Then he talks about the workaround which is the same you found].,

You are right in wondering why this doesn't work and, to me, all the other answers fail to address this properly. In fact it's a non sense, and as Crockford says it's a mistake in the design of the language and it could be quite confusing.

Comment: thanks, i have not already read that book, i will complete reading the amazing book sometime!

Comment: Crockford's correct that `this` shouldn't refer to the global object, but I think it would cause all sorts of weirdness if `this` were to refer to whatever it was in the lexically enclosing scope when the function was instantiated.

Comment: @Pointy can you elaborate on why you think so?

Comment: @Geeo well I'd have to spend some time contemplating it, but it sets off alarm bells in my head :-)  I know that there are plans for that to be the case for some situations in a future version of the language ("Harmony" I think).